# How to return the length of a new variable created with New-Variable

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script that creates new variables as needed and I have them working fine. What I need now is to return the length of the those variables.

This of course returns the value of '6'

```powershell
$strText = "Yellow"
$strText.length
```

But here's where I'm having trouble. This returns '1.length'

```powershell
$bar = 1
New-Variable "foo$bar" "hello"
write-host $foo$bar.length
```

and this returns 'foo1.length'

```powershell
$bar = 1
New-Variable "foo$bar" "hello"
write-host foo$bar.length
```

I'm obviously looking for '5' in this case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Get-Variable` cmdlet](http://ss64.com/ps/get-variable.html) for this:

```powershell
write-host (Get-Variable foo$bar -Value).length
```

Demo:

```powershell
PS > $bar = 1
PS > New-Variable "foo$bar" "hello"
PS > write-host (Get-Variable foo$bar -Value).length
5
PS >
```

Comment: @Downvoter - Any reason for the downvote?  I would be happy to correct my answer if you have found a problem with it.